mysql connection url password not being recognized
I have no idea why this won't work, I have a mysql connection url with the password specified but every time I am getting an error that says I am not using a password
elle@MacBook-Air ~ % mysql mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/database
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

elle@MacBook-Air ~ % mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.3.0 for macos14.2 on arm64 (Homebrew)

Tried to connect to my local MySQL database but I'm unable to with the connection url

This is not the correct way of using the mysql client command line. You need to provide the correct parameters mysql -u yourUser -p database it will then ask for your password (unless the client on this version accepts this :D )

That kind of URI notation is accepted with MySQL Shell (new recommended command line client). You can specify the mysql:// or mysqlx:// protocol and the rest of the attributes like you did. MySQL Shell command is mysqlsh
